# How to enable WebKitDeveloperExtras on Android's WebView

Tags: android, webkit, webview, web-inspector

If I write a native Android application that uses android.webkit.WebView, how do I enable WebKitDeveloperExtras for it? I would like to be able to enable real script debugging via Web Inspector, not just dumping to a console.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15124393/638966) might help. It recommends using [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) to debug Chrome on android. Might get you at least part way there.

Comment: You could also enable the webkit inspector everywhere on a Mac by running `defaults write -g WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true` in the terminal. I don't have an Android project to confirm unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Although the WebView is based off the WebKit Rendering Engine, I believe that is all it has in common with browsers such as Chrome and Safari. As such I do not believe there is a way to get the DeveloperExtras.