# how to enable WebKit's remote debugging/inspector of Android app using WebView?

Tags: android, webview, webkit, remote-debugging, web-inspector

I need to inspect javascript execution (webview widget) in an android application,
 while debugging; through SDK & usb cable and/or http/websockets;
 from destop computer (e.g. chrome running on desktop).

Webkit's sources includes DebuggerServer implementation
 ( platform_external_webkit\Source\WebKit\android\wds\DebugServer.cpp )
 accessible at cpp level, and bound if flag WDS is enabled (at build time?)

Source\WebKit\android\jni\WebCoreFrameBridge.cpp:#if ENABLE(WDS)
Source\WebKit\android\jni\WebCoreFrameBridge.cpp:    WDS::server()->addFrame(frame);

The default port for server is 9999

The sources show that all is implemented (at Cpp level) to enable the feature,
 but I have not found any reference searching the web for experiences
 using live debugging at javascript level in adroid devices automating
 webkit's inspector interface.

1.- Are the feature present, in binary form, executing in actual android devices?
 (has adroid's distribution of webkit been built without WDS flag enabled? :-( )

2.- Can the remote debug feature be enabled/used from javascript or application
 (at java level) e.g. at startup of app?

3.- In case it is possible to enable the webkit inspector/debugger feature,
 how to make it possible to interact from remote application ? (e.g. from
 another javascript app using websockets, or chrome on desktop computers).

Some paragraphs explaining the mechanics like
  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#remote
 would be nice!

thanks in advance for any information, or references about this topic.
I consider important to enable remote debugging (in the device) at
 javascript level to make it possible modern development of HTML5
 applications and happy debugging experience.

cheers,
Ale.

Comment: [Debug xwalkview or webview remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692358/6521116)

Answer (score 8):

> **For android >= 4.4 (kitkat)**

See [Remote debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

> **For android < 4.4 (Lower versions)**

Use very good open source tool: [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Installing.html). See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEqwnpLYnI0&feature=youtu.be) video for help to use it.
If you are familiar with grunt then you can use [grunt-weinre](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-weinre)

For quick view:

1. install weinre using npm
2. Do the [configuration](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-weinre#recommended-usage) in your gruntfile.
3. Run the weinre grunt task.
4. Use this script to inject the weinre target code into your web page.

5. Open http://localhost:8082 in your browser and you will find devices running above script. You can debug all this devices.

**NOTE:** if you want to debug webview/browser in your mobile device then you need to replace localhost with your machine's IP running weinre. And yes, all the devices should be on the same network.

Comment: Thank you very much!! With help of your answer, video link, weinre and grunt-weinre I was able to debug ionic WebView running on android < 4.4

Answer (score 5):

Now it is easy with Android 4.4. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Comment: Thats great, but how about Android < 4.4, I realy need to debug Galaxy S3 that uses Android 4.3

Answer (score 3):

You can do remote debugging targeting the Android Browser with the [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) project. Or use [Chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) with the Chrome for Android browser. As far as I know, you can't target a WebView directly, but targeting the Android Browser should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done, because the debugger backend code is not there. The source code you are referencing to is a copy of webkit source in android, but it is not compiled into android release bits.

Answer (score 0):

Pre KitKat [jsHyBugger](https://www.jshybugger.com/#!/) works well ( trial version and annual single user license €29 )

( I have no connection to the developers / have purchased a license )