# Dev Tools for Native Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, debugging

I haven't done much development for Android, and I am looking to debug some JS/CSS in the native Android Internet browser (Version 4.1.2). So far, I have found the ADB extension for Chrome on Android, but not much in the way of the native browser.

I am seeing some strange anomalies in my JS/CSS appear in the native Android browser that I do not see in the Chrome browser or on iOS devices.

I'm looking for guidance/recommendations/suggestions/tools that I can use for debugging JS/CSS on the native Android browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801819/how-to-enable-webkits-remote-debugging-inspector-of-android-app-using-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jsHybugger App to find your JS/CSS anomalies. Just install the APK on your device and use the ADB extension for Chrome on your desktop to debug your webpage. The jsHybugger App acts as a proxy between the native Android Browser and your webserver, and enables you to debug your page.

The software is not free but there is a cheap shorttime license available.
https://www.jshybugger.com