# How to debug webview remotely?

Tags: android, debugging, android-webview, inspect

How can I do debug/inspect element of apk webview.
I have tried [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) but it is helpful only for chrome not for apk.

Please suggest me

Comment: [Debug webview remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13801819/6521116)

Comment: [Debug xwalkview or webview remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692358/6521116)

Answer (score 94):

Try this:

1. Enable Developer Options in Device (Settings-->About Phone-->Tap 7 times on build number)
2. Turn on Developer options and Enable USB Debugging (in Developer Options)
3. Add this line in your custom Application class or in the Activity where the Web View is loaded

   // if your build is in debug mode, enable inspecting of web views

   ```
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
   ```
4. Open Chrome and type `chrome://inspect/#devices` and you should see your device in the Remote Target List
5. Click on inspect to debug it.

**Update:**
You can simplify it like below:

```
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Does it require phone to be connected with USB? Also what if I am testing the app in a simulator?

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev yes you need to connect with USB. If you want to connect without USB see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442586/2462531

Comment: Why did you an edit? I believe it was correct with a single & sign

Comment: @ReDetection Rollbacked, I thought that I was missing one more & sign

Comment: A bit up-to-date way: WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)

Comment: and how to debug live page ?

Answer (score 12):

This is what worked for me, override the method `onCreate` in `MainActivity.java` and add this line in the method `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)`.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
package com.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myapp";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //added this line with necessary imports at the top.
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Build your code, open your app in phone and go to chrome://inspect , You would see your app listed over there. Click on inspect link.

Comment: Thanks for this. FYI on React Native `v0.57.3` there is no need to import `android.os.Bundle` as it's no longer required for `onCreate()` method

Comment: I don't think the onCreate method exists anymore, I get the error `no suitable method found for onCreate(no arguments)`

Answer (score 5):

If what you are looking for is a way to turn on WebView debugging for an app that you **don't** have the source code to, this can be done but you will need to decompile and recompile the app.

The instructions on how to do this can he found here: https://blog.speedfox.co.uk/articles/1524219174-Android_WebView_Hackery

Answer (score 3):

To debug webviews in the android app, you have to set WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true) in the WebviewActivity

Open chrome://inspect/#device to debug. Use port forwarding.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Answer (score 3):

In react-native-webview they give an explanation for both IOS and Android.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Debugging.md

Helped me on IOS.

Answer (score 2):

I have see there is a chapter for webView.Have you try out? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Seems it need:

- An Android device or emulator running Android 4.4 or later, with USB debugging enabled as described in 2. Enable USB debugging on your device .
- Chrome 30 or later.

Comment: Hi Clijac, I have seen that section. It allows only url to debug in chrome, whereas I want something using which I can debug apk which has webview in that.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first you have to enable debugging in your app as it was showed by others.
2. Connect phone to comp by usb or tcp.
3. Then open chromium based browser.
4. Open chrome://inspect/#devices. You will see the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuYeC.png).
5. Open devtools.
6. Browse "Elements" tab and find container with such id. Copy [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNAvZ.png).
7. Run  "adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:[copied part]"

Now you can forward port 9222 to remote machine and open debugger there.