# Adb over wireless without usb cable at all for not rooted phones

Tags: android, remote-debugging, android-wifi

I want to debug Android APPs on my phone (LG nexus 4). I'm travelling and I forgot my USB cable. When I work at home I can do it just connecting the USB cable and executing the command 'adb tcpip 5555'. Then I can unplug the USB cable and connect via 'adb connect IP'.

But now I cannot execute the first command because I don't have a cable. I don't understand why I have to do it every time, since I already execute the 'adb tcpip' command before.

What I tried now:

I installed a terminal application on my Android and tried to execute that command there, but I received a "device not found" error. Maybe he cannot see himself...

I search for any reasonable option in "Android Development Options" and enabled everything seemed to have relation with Wifi. But nothing helped.

I search StackOverflow, but all answers I found involving connect via USB cable before. Is there I way to do this connection without the need of a cable at all?

Some info: 
My Nexus 4 isn't rooted. 
The android version is 5.1.1.

Comment: I understand you're trying to find a technical solution for it, but, isn't easier to just buy a cable?

Comment: it would be easier, but where I am there is no usb cables being sold around.

Comment: When you get home, buy a bunch of micro USB cables on eBay or elsewhere. Scatter them liberally throughout your luggage. :-) With respect to your problem, though, AFAIK only certain devices (e.g., Fire TV) are set up to do adb-over-TCP/IP on a full-time basis, for developers that opt into this. I am not aware of any workaround for other devices. "I don't understand why I have to do it every time" -- security, I imagine.

Comment: I have a bunch of this cables at home, but it is not so useful if I forget them =). So if there is no way I will go to the town tomorrow and try to find a place that sells it. :)

Comment: see my answer, it might help; I understand why ur trying to find tech solution for this but I dont understand why on earth they didnt update adb so we can use it remotely  automatically without setup commands.. I made shell script for that so now I need only to type 1 command to connect but still it is so annoying and sometimes it disconnect itself. Its 2015, 2016 soon, new notebooks doesnt even have LAN ports anymore and wireless charging is behind the corner. Google wakey, wakey

Comment: Good question but wrong marked answer. SO must do something about this type of questions and selected answers.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani What's the correct answer in your opinion?

Comment: None of them didn't answer to your question, there is no way to use WiFi without USB cable in not-rooted devices. the marked answer works for you?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I didn't try. I give up and a day later I bought a usb cable. at that time the answer seemed the most plausible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. how you deleted the marked answer btw? :D

Comment: I didn't... I just unmark it :)

Comment: For those saying "just buy a cable", my USB port no longer responds (I charge wireless), I do not have that option, but still want to debug. Phone is fine apart from that, repairing is a bit expensive for just a USB port :)

Comment: @Martijn Also in the jungle, where I was, there was no option to buy a cable. :)

Comment: ALSO for those saying "buy a cable" there are other reasons to want to forgo using USB, such as sending conifg you can only set up over adb which the device periodically forgets.  In that case, it's just a single command, but if it could be done over WiFi it could be automated.  And some of us are locked out of being able to root our phones to do it as root.

Comment: There's plenty of "as far as I know" and "it seems" around the impossibility of non-rooted adb with no cable at any time, but can anyone find anything in the docs or specs or anywhere else that it is expressly forbidden, even without an explanation?

Comment: Android 11+ has a developer option Wireless Debugging.  Then use adb pair ipaddr:port   https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

Comment: **TL;DR:** Google actively and deliberately made this not possible. You will not find a solution below. **The only correct answer is to not buy any product over which you don’t have full control.** As such devices are crimes that are strangely still “legal”. Prevent such organized crime (Yes, organized crime. I has to be said.), and buy one of the many phones where the bootloader is not locked. E.g. a Fairpone.

Comment: The question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate of another, and the other question is closed anyway. In 2023 the correct answer is to use `adb pair` command. Set the phone up with ADB Over Wireless, then 'Pair device with pairing code'. Then from commandline, `adb pair ip:port` that's shown, and enter the code.

Answer (score 31):

*The question is about a non rooted device but if it is rooted the simplest way would be to:*

From the terminal on your phone, do this:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1715829) for full details.

Comment: Note that the question states that the device is not rooted, so `su` will not be available.

Comment: I cannot execute the su command. I received "command not found". Maybe cause it is not rooted? I execute the setprop command without su but I received "cannot set property".

Comment: Sorry I missed the "not rooted" part...

Comment: You don't need su to make it work on all of my devices [around 10], hopefully this is a standard thing.

Comment: Question states "for not rooted phones", this answer doesn't meet that criteria. Why is it the most upvoted answer?

Comment: This answer should be removed as it is clearly not valid, totally misses the point

Comment: This is  a good answer for readers brought here by search engines, who also missed the non rooted part of the question

Comment: but it didn't work for me, `adb connect 192.168.1.105` says `unable to connect to 192.168.1.105:5555 connection refused`

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question that was asked, but is exactly what I was searching for! Needed the command to set up a start-up script. Many thanks!!

Comment: Just figured you can also set setprop persist to make the change permanent --> setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555

Comment: Thank you. It is very hard to find a solution for rooted device

Comment: @JasonWaltz is it safe to set it permanently? it's kinda open port, if I understand it right?

Comment: For a non-rooted device you can now use pairing code: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-up-wireless-debugging-android-11-send-adb-commands-without-usb-cable-0302898/

Answer (score 26):

We can do it without a USB cable at all in the following ways.

**NEW UPDATE**: (Latest Answer without using USB cable at all)

**Note: It will work only when your laptop and mobile should connect to the same WiFi.**

> Go to [developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) from the mobile settings and enable `Wireless Debugging`

- Step 1: In Android Studio choose "Pair Devices Using Wi-Fi" from the Device Connections dropdown.

[image]

- Step 2: In Mobile go to settings and search for "Pair using QR code" and scan the QR code

[image]

Thats it!, Now you connected your mobile without USB at all.

For your question

> Adb over wireless **without USB cable at all** for non rooted phones.

*Old Answer:*

You need to connect your device to your computer via USB cable. Make sure USB debugging is working. You can check if it shows up when running `adb devices`.

Open cmd in ...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

> Step1: Run `adb devices`

Ex: C:\pathToSDK\platform-tools>adb devices

You can check if it shows up when running adb devices.

> Step2: Run `adb tcpip 5555`

Ex: C:\pathToSDK\platform-tools>adb tcpip 5555

Disconnect your device (remove the USB cable).

> Step3: Go to the Settings -> About phone -> Status to view the IP address of your phone.

> Step4: Run `adb connect <IP address of your device>:5555`

Ex: C:\pathToSDK\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.0.2

> Step5: Run `adb devices` again, you should see your device.

Now you can execute adb commands or use your favorite IDE for android development - wireless!

Now you might ask, what do I have to do when I move into a different workspace and change WiFi networks? You do not have to repeat steps 1 to 3 (these set your phone into WiFi-debug mode). You do have to connect to your phone again by executing steps 4 to 6.

Unfortunately, the android phones lose the WiFi-debug mode when restarting. Thus, if your battery died, you have to start over. Otherwise, if you keep an eye on your battery and do not restart your phone, you can live without a cable for weeks!

See [here](https://shylendramadda.blogspot.com/2017/10/android-run-app-without-usb-cable-need.html) for more

Ref: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root

**UPDATE 1:**

**If you set `C:\pathToSDK\platform-tools` this path in Environment variables then there is no need to repeat all steps, you can simply use only Step 4 that's it, it will connect to your device**.

To set a path:
My Computer-> Right click--> properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> edit `path` in System variables -> paste the `platform-tools` path in variable value -> ok -> ok -> ok

**UPDATE 2:**

- Go to the android terminal
- adb tcpip 5555
- adb connect your_ip_address

Comment: @Down voter May I know what is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: You wrote: "You need to connect your device to your computer via USB cable". The question is "without usb cable at all". This is not an answer.

Comment: @Agent_L For at least one you need to connect USB (until you switch off your mobile or change network)

Comment: And as you see in accepted answer comment even the Bluetooth version needs a USB-cable too to setup the device ;)

Comment: wait, i checked it on windows and its working, however when i use linux  it disconnects when im trying to enable hot reload (long press on hardware device button) is there any cure for that?

Comment: I start to think, that this is a network faulty, because we have dhcp server installed and there might be ip changes while laptop and device is connected... thats just assuming.

Comment: Yep, you should connect with same network in your device and PC/ Laptop

Comment: Deviec connected but not installing the apk. Please Helpp

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan What is the issue? any error or Log?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda There was no issue. first time it takes long time to install the apk. Thankyou

Comment: Oh it's okay that depends on your RAM.

Comment: Down vote - It can be done with console connection this is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327918/391691 please link to it

Comment: @Simson Those commands(`su, setprop`) not allowed in windows terminal. How can you use it?

Comment: Not the windows terminal, the android terminal

Comment: In android terminal also `'su' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: How to find pathToSdk?

Comment: @MayankKataria It is usually located at `C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` if you use windows.

Comment: It is not working if I am on a VPN, why is that ?

Comment: @brij May you need to post it as a new question. I am not sure

Comment: This works without usb cable, Can we connect the same way from terminal without Android studio?

Comment: @MaheshJamdade Yes you can if you set the path for `platform-tools` as I mentioned in the `UPDATE 1:`

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer anyone who is wondering you need to enable connecting using adb wireless in your developer settings and connect with code `adb pair <ipaddress: port>` and enter passcode when prompted (Ensure both your devices are on same network.)

Comment: oh great to hear that from you! @MaheshJamdade

Comment: It used to work before for me, but now it doesn't for my Pixel 7 Pro! What a turn off!

Comment: Check your developer settings enabled in your mobile

Comment: @Agent_L Check my updated answer in `NEW UPDATE`  "Without USB at all"

Answer (score 21):

Had same issue, however I'm using Macbook Pro (2016) which has USB-c only and I forgot my adapter at home.

Since unable to run adb at all on my development machine, I found a different approach.

Connecting phone with USB cable to another computer (in same WiFi) and enable run adb tcpip from there.

> Master-machine : computer where development goes on, with only USB-C connectors
>
> Slave-machine: another computer with USB and in same WiFi

### Steps:

1. Connect the phone to a different computer (slave-machine)
2. Run `adb usb && adb tcpip 5555` from there
3. On master machine

   ```
   deko$: adb devices
   List of devices attached

   deko$: adb connect 10.0.20.153:5555
   connected to 10.0.20.153:5555
   ```
4. Now Android Studio or Xamarin can install and run app on the phone

---

> ***Sidenote:***
>
> I also tested Bluetooth tethering from the Phone to Master-machine and successfully connected to phone. Both Android Studio and Xamarin worked well, however the upload process, from Xamarin was taking long time. But it works.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. For beginner, I would like to add that with adb connect ipaddress, here enter your devices ip address. Which can be found under Settings ---> About Phone ---> Status

Comment: question was "without USB"

Comment: This doesn't solve the main problem, not having a cable.

Comment: I never said this is the only solution. But considering upvotes I'd say it sure is an alternative solution. For some it's what works and for other not

Comment: not an answer to the question

Comment: This is why SO sucks.  "How to do something without USB" Answer: "Step 1. Plug in USB." WTF?  And the response "oh, it works for some people" is like telling someone without a lug wrench to grab their lug wrench to change a tire in the middle of nowhere and claiming "oh, some people use lug wrenches, so it's helpful."  Just because you answer a _completely different question_ doesn't mean it's helpful for _THIS_ question. Howmever you think you've helped is completely irrelevant on this page.  Stop trying to _post hoc_ rationalize. 

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug, Stackoverflow is not only for *getting the only answer that solves the problem, but rather, getting possible solutions and workarounds for the problem.*. In some situations there might not be a possibility of getting what you need, but getting some solutions that might be useful for someone is better than getting no solution at all. Please note that SO is not only for the person who asked the question, but, it is also for people who are having a similar problem (not the same), so that, others can try what suits best for them.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

If the adb connection is ever lost:

Make sure that your host is still connected to the same Wi-Fi network your Android device is.
Reconnect by executing the "adb connect IP" step. (IP is obviously different when you change location.)
Or if that doesn't work, reset your adb host:
    `adb kill-server`
and then start over from the beginning.

Comment: after killing server and then reconnecting it works.

Comment: The question was how to do this once and after that do not use cable anymore even after reboot. Your answer doesn't solve the problem if it does then there's a missing step I believe

Answer (score 0):

If usb is not working you should checkout debugging over bluetooth (Without Rooting)

http://zcourts.com/2013/07/19/android-debugging-over-bluetooth-without-root/#sthash.hVCLtWSk.dpbs

Comment: the bluetooth version needs a usb-cable too to setup the device

Comment: Second link worked for me on non-rooted device...
adb tcpip 4455
adb connect 192.168.44.1:4455

Comment: I tried the second way, but it seems you need to connect via USB first. When trying without connecting to USB first it says "Connection refused. Unable to connect"

Answer (score -4):

type in Windows cmd.exe

```
    cd %userprofile%\.android
    dir
    copy adbkey.pub adb_keys
    dir
```

copy the file **adb_keys** to your phone folder **/data/misc/adb**. Reboot the phone. RSA Key is now authorized.

from:
[How to solve ADB device unauthorized in Android ADB host device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device)

now follow the instructions for adb connect, or use any app for preparing. i prefer **ADB over WIFI Widget** from Mehdy Bohlool, it works without root.

from:
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: sorry i think it is not possible to access /data partition without root. but i have used this method for broken usb connector without root. first i did a backup from stock recovery, then i extracted adb_keys from backup

Answer (score -10):

**Connect android phone without using USB cable except XIAOMI PHONES** 
== MAKE SURE THAT YOUR PHONE HAS USB DEBUGGING ENABLED == 
== **IP Address** series should **NOT** be '0' like 192.168.**0**.10 
1. Connect your PC (Laptop) and Android phone to same wifi network. 
2. Go to the Android SDK folder > platform-tools and open command prompt by holding the shift key and right clicking on the folder. 
3. Type the command "adb tcpip 5555", and hit Enter, sometimes it gives an error but ignore it and go ahead. 
4. Type "adb connect [YOUR PHONE IP]". example: "adb connect 192.168.1.34" and hit enter, your phone will be connected to PC.

Comment: The adb tcpip command will only work when connected with an USB cable