# Android Debug Bridge stops running on Samsung A20e

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adb

I have the following problem.
A while after connecting my phone via `adb` tcpip... over wifi to my laptop for debugging/app installation,
the connections fails.
But:
When using `adb devices -l`, phone is still shown. Furthermore in Android Studio I can choose the phone as device, but when doing so, after building the application android studio starts background tasks: 'waiting for device to come online' or 'launching app install' like forever.

I tried
Restarting Phone & Laptop

```
adb kill-server
```

switching debug mode off&on again
-> all without result

factory reset
-> `adb` worked again for a few minutes till an hour (not sure) then same issue occurred again...

please help and thank you

Comment: How did you connect via Tcpip, can you post those cmds? Have a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442586/2462531

Comment: Yes I did it with Android things ( connecting adb through IP) , but there's a problem with adb and android studio!. I think when create your adb connection via IP android studio can listen this new device. But if you lose connection, Android studio doesn't handle this problem. The only solution I had is to kill all adb and android studio and restart with adb connect 192.168.x.x ( but sometimes I can't have logcat after 1 hour)

Comment: my commands: (1) adb tcpip 5555 (2) adb connect ip.address.phone:5555

Comment: killing and restarting unfortunatly didn't work for me

Comment: But you restart your phone each time ? You can see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp