# chrome device debugger not recognizing web pages opened from instagram application

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, instagram

i have a problem or a bug in my webpage that happens only in webview that is being opened from Instagram application on mobile devices.

i am using chrome device debugger tool in my mac desktop by connecting my device through usb `chrome://inspect/#devices` to debug my webpage js code.

normal web pages that are being opened from chrome browser in my phone is being recognized in chrome devtools in my desktop and there is no problem here.

the problem is that when I am trying to open a link from Instagram application it opens an internal browser from Instagram app and the problem is that chrome devtools is not recognizing that web pages being opened from inside Instagram app.

is there is any solution that allows me to debug Instagram application webview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug webview remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903934/how-to-debug-webview-remotely)

Comment: @JoshLee the problem is that it works in most of the webviews and it only fails in instagram webview.\

Comment: Any solution to this?