# Android styling in WebView not being applied

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

Hi I am currently trying to render some html files and their styling, that are stored locally in the android phone (emulator), the html is being displayed but the styling is not being applied. All html contained the this `<link href="swscustom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
and this styling sheet contains this `@import url(activitytype.css);`. How can I apply all stylings?

Activity with function:

```
private const val RESULT_FOLDER_NAME = "results"

class ShowResultsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    private lateinit var prevButton: ImageButton
    private lateinit var nextButton: ImageButton

    private val results = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var currentIndex = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_results)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        prevButton = findViewById(R.id.prevButton)
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton)

        loadResults()
        showResult()
    }

    private fun loadResults() {
        val folder = File(filesDir, RESULT_FOLDER_NAME)
        val resultsFiles = folder.listFiles() {_, name -> name.endsWith(".html")}

        resultsFiles?.forEach { results.add(it.readText()) }
    }

    private fun showResult() {
        val result = results[currentIndex]
        val basePath = "file://${filesDir.absolutePath}/$RESULT_FOLDER_NAME/"

//        val htmlWithBaseURL = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='${basePath}result.css'></head><body>$result</body></html>"
        println(basePath)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(basePath, result, "text/html", "UTF=8", null)
    }

    fun showPreviousResult(view: View) {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex--
            showResult()
        }
    }

    fun showNextResult(view: View) {
        if (currentIndex < results.size - 1) {
            currentIndex++
            showResult()
        }
    }

}
```

HTML and CSS files stored locally:

[image: HTML and CSS files]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting your webview and seeing if there are any errors?

Comment: Yes? I can see just the html files being rendered in the webview, and Logcat does not show any error,

Comment: I was not talking about LogCat, but rather the console in the webview itself.

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903934/how-to-debug-webview-remotely)

Comment: Cool, the console there shows me this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED. I have an idea on what to do, if not as last resource I just put the css inside the assets folder.